# NSAttributedString size calculation returns different results with .usesFontLeading option

Tags: ios, swift

TLDR; I found out that `.usesFontLeading` return the different result in iOS 13, but I want to know why ?

---

I have a bug in iOS 13 that my app shows the wrong text height. This bug does not happen in iOS 12.

I have the code to calculate the multi-line height of `NSAttributedString`.

I found that with different options, one has font leading, another one does not. The code returns different results.

```swift
let height_with_font_leading = text.boundingRect(with: constraintSize,
                                                 options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                                 context: nil).height

let height_with_no_font_leading = text.boundingRect(with: constraintSize,
                                                    options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin],
                                                    context: nil).height
```

The height from the calculations are shown as images below.

[image: with_font_leading][image: without_font_leading]

As you see, the height **without** `.usesFontLeading` is correct, because the label can show full text without truncation.

1. What is the purpose of `.usesFontLeading` ?
2. When should I use it ?

Here is the full snippet of my code:

https://gist.github.com/nRewik/7760ac31f107642c70eb9e659862ac3b